# Flutter | How to add a SizedBox() as the last item of a ListView.builder()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to put some space or a SizedBox() as the last item of the ListView,
because the FloatingActionButton() is hiding some information from the last ListTile.

I want to scroll to the space/SizeBox() like WhatsApp for example.[image]

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: cardsList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          ListTile( ... ),
          Divider( ... ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListView` has padding property

```
body: ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
    itemCount: cardsList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          ListTile( ... ),
          Divider( ... ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Well, that was fast.
another quistion please, why you used a const before EdgeInsets ?

Comment: I'm using `flutter_lints: ^1.0.4 # https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints` package and overrides rule `prefer_const_constructors: true` so now analyser ask me to add `cont` keyword if it's possible

Comment: You can use the `const` keyword because `EdgeInsets` has a const constructor. It allow the framework to not rebuild it every time the widget tree need to rebuilt but to reload it as is from the cache. Performance up

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `ListView` with the `Column` widget. In that widget add the `SizedBox`. Like this:

```
body: Column(
  children: [
    ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cardsList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            ListTile( ... ),
            Divider( ... ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 50.0)
  ]
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that made alot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```dart
 ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cardsList.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            index < items.length ? myListTile() : SizedBox(),
      ),
```

Comment: `myListTile()` is `Column( children: [ ListTile( ... ), Divider( ... ), ], );` in your case.